# how to improve performance by using GCD

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have situation where I need to fetch data from five different tables when user logging in presently I am fetching data normally so it is taking more time to fetch data (in my case it's 1 min), how to improve performance by using GCD. Can any one help me out?

Comment: I would create one service that gets all the information with one http request. thats the best solution if applicable.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your existing code. What do you mean by "fetching data from tables"?

Answer (score 0):

try wrtitng your fetching data code such as method call for fetching data in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self performSelector:@selector(getItemsFromWebservice) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
            });
```

Comment: i have 5 methods so i need to create 5 dispatch_get_main_queue( ) so all these are running on main thread thus this will be a burden on main thread?

Comment: try to call 5 methods in only 1 dispatch_get_main_queue()

Comment: It will take the same time if all called in the same dispatch queue

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code for fetching data. I Think it may help you.

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
                dispatch_async(q, ^
                               {
                                   [self yourMethod];
                               });
```

Comment: so i need to create 5 global queue and call them right?

Comment: Yes.It depends upon your functionality or requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
    //Fetch data from one table
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Update UI
    });
});
```

Use it five times.This will get  a global concurrent queue.So,five fetch task will execute concurrently。

Answer (score 0):

Create one service that gets all the information with one http request. thats the best solution if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^ {
        [self fetchMethod1];
    });
    //......
    dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^ {
        [self fetchMethod5];
    });

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
        // update UI
    });
```

Comment: so how to identify fetching of each method is completed? and in my sceniro if all methods data is fetched i should redirect user to new view should i do it in notify method else where should i do it

Comment: @user3816512 when all methods is completed, block in `dispatch_group_notify ` will be called

Comment: @user3816512 Yes, you should redirect in notify method